# Can we list a J2ee web application in AppExchange?

Tags: appexchange, java

I am trying to list my web application in AppExchange platform. I tried reading through salesforce and app exchange sites but could not dig deeper into the answer.

If I can list my web application the following are my questions:-

Can I use MySql database? If not what are the databases supported? Or will I have to develop the whole web app from scratch using Apex?

Will I have to change my payment gateway to suit Salesforce needs?
If it's possible what will the testing approach be (tools that can be used for testing)?

What would be the steps for implementing the same.

Any clarifications and suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Is the following statwement correct "AppExchange is an online marketplace of integrated third party applications built for the Salesforce.com"

Comment: Can we list only solutions that are for salesforce.com or only plugins developed for salesforce.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely list applications that integrate with Salesforce as opposed to being directly hosted on the platform. That said, you'll still be subject to the security review process to ensure that you won't be causing any security concerns with client's data etc.

It sounds like you might have a good candidate app [for the Force.com Canvas](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Canvas).

With regards to your payment portal you really haven't provided enough information to comment but that seems like a very open ended question that doesn't really fit this site too well anyway. The developer discussion boards could be a good place to discuss that.

Comment: Hi LaceySnr, Thanks for the reply.
So I understand that I can only list my application on AppExchange and need not Host my Application in SalesForce environment.
Further I need not do anything but redirect users to my hosted application on clicking from AppExchange. Please correct me If I am wrong

Comment: I believe you can redirect people through to your website for more information, yes. You'll still need to be registered as a Salesforce ISV partner which is a lengthy process in itself.

Comment: Yes I just got registered with SalesForce via partner program. Thanks for the update. Can you please hint me on the process of listing as can I just add a visualsource page which will redirect or any other standard better approach. Sorry If I am asking too many things at once.

Comment: Probably should be a new question, but you need to create a developer org via the partner portal, create a managed package and then submit that for security review.